# UWP get the names of app's assembly files at runtime

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm looking to display a list of the dll assemblies that our UWP references at build time during the running app. I can see these dependencies in the Debug\AppX folder. I've looked for them in the members of both Package and Assembly. Are they visible to the running application?

I've been looking through the members of:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Package package = Package.Current;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

 var files = await appInstalledFolder.GetFilesAsync()

foreach(var file in files){

if(file.Name.Contains("dll"){
//do something here
}
```